# How to fix iOS Facebook login error with message: "Login error there is an error in logging you into this application"?

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, facebook-login

[iOS Facebook login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ4Nh.jpg)

I spent a lot of time searching the internet for a solution. I found many solutions for android but not for iOS. I use react-native-fbsdk for log in Facebook. My react-native version is 0.66.5.

I tried change react-native version, re-integrated Facebook login on iOS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you end up solving this issue ? I am currently experiencing it myself on iOS as well